# How can I obtain an AutomationElement reference to an application running in the Windows Phone 7 Emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7, ui-automation

Windows Phone's Silverlight support includes support for the `System.Windows.Automation` classes, but there doesn't appear to be any way to get an `AutomationElement` reference to the application from outside the emulator (from a .NET 4 test client, similar to the way you would access a Silverlight application).

I have tried:

- Using `AutomationElement.FromHandle` on the XDE window, but that only gives me automation elements for the window itself (no doubt because the emulator is a VM)
- Snooping around in Microsoft.Smartdevice.Connectivity, but there doesn't seem to be anything useful there

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automation is not supported in the initial release ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137528/ui-automation-for-wp7

Comment: Thanks, [this has also been confirmed](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/82604/498587.aspx) by Mark Chamberlain (MSFT)