# Unit Testing in VS 2010 Express for Windows Phone

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-express, visual-c#-express-2010

I am developing a Windows Phone 7 project and wish to test the app's business logic (i.e. just the vanilla C# code) within stand-alone unit tests, run on Windows from the command line (from Jenkins) rather than on a device.

What's the best way of achieving this using the free Express tools only?

Currently I am thinking of:

- Developing the main WP7 project using VS Express WP as usual
- Having a build script copy the WP7 code and generate a VC# console project file containing each source file
- Create unit test code in this second project using Visual C# 2010 Express
- Compile test code for Windows and run unit tests using NUnit, Express Unit or similar.

Sounds like a whole lot of hassle, does anyone have experience of a nicer option than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this question: [State of unit testing for Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994672/state-of-unit-testing-for-windows-phone)

It has some nice ideas and hints and I am afraid that it isn't much better at this time.