# Visual Studio 2012 unit tests try to load older versions of assemblies

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mstest, windows-phone-8

I seem to be unable to run any unit test. All the errors are along following lines:

```
    Test method TvQueue.UnitTesting.TheTvDb.TheTvDbServiceTest.GetShowbasicTest threw exception: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = JKRTABLET\Jan
LOG: DisplayName = System.Windows, Version=2.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Jan/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/TvQueue/TvQueue.UnitTesting/bin/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : TvQueue.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v7.0\Bin\JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR4.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Windows, Version=2.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Jan/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/TvQueue/TvQueue.UnitTesting/bin/Debug/System.Windows.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Jan/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/TvQueue/TvQueue.UnitTesting/bin/Debug/System.Windows/System.Windows.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Jan/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/TvQueue/TvQueue.UnitTesting/bin/Debug/System.Windows.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Jan/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/TvQueue/TvQueue.UnitTesting/bin/Debug/System.Windows/System.Windows.EXE.

    at TvQueue.Data.TheTvDb.TheTvDbService.<GetShow>d__8.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start(ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start(ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
   at TvQueue.Data.TheTvDb.TheTvDbService.GetShow(Int64 theTvDbId)
   at TvQueue.UnitTesting.TheTvDb.TheTvDbServiceTest.<GetShowbasicTest>d__0.MoveNext() in TheTvDbServiceTest.cs: line 19
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

I get this problem when developing Windows Phone 8 code. For some reason, MSTest wants to load older versions of assemblies (the assemblies actually referenced in the project are 4.x or higher, MSTest wants to load 2.x versions).

I suspect this is a configuration issue, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see my answer on [How to use MSTest in VS2010 for Windows Phone 8 applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13035195/95309)

> the assemblies actually referenced in the project are 4.x or higher

`System.Windows, Version=2.0.6.0` isn't a old version, it's the correct new version. And you can't actually see the version number of the individual assemblies, are there are no such thing as individual assemblies.

Remember the main change is that Windows Phone 8, like Windows RT, no longer uses direct assemblies, but WinMD files that compiles several assemblies into a single API.