# WP8 Unit test FileNotFoundException only while using MSTest.exe

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-phone-8

I created a new Windows Phone Unit Test project for WP8. It works fine when started directly from visual studio, but when I run it from VS Command Prompt using `MSTest.exe` I get the following errors:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Can not load file 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies.
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Can not load file 'Microsoft.Phone, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24eec0d8c86cda1e' or one of its dependencies.

No dependencies beside the ones from project template have been added. Any ideas what is causing this and how to solve this error ? It's vital for me to run the tests from `MSTest.exe` by a third party application, not the VS itself.

Comment: be sure to copy all referenced dlls to folder where MSTest.exe and test units are executed

Comment: But I am not using any external dlls. I created simple unit test project with standard test method and simple Assert.AreEqual(1,1).

Comment: have you seen this topic at msdn - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0b2e95d8-79d5-4734-946b-fe8a2fd51a52/mstest-cannot-load-assembly?forum=vststest Maybe it can help

Comment: Thanks for the link but It didn't help. I created empty solution and added 3 Unit Test projects (one for WP8, one for windows store and one for .net). No additional dependencies. All of them are working when run directly from VS2012. But when I try to run them via MSTest only non-WP and non-WindowsStore test is working. I tried changing platform from x86 to Any, x64 or ARM but still no go. Would be nice if you did the same - new project from scratch with just one simple test method and told me if It's working for you or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at `VSTest.Console.exe` tool? It is a replacement of `MSTest.exe` in Visual Studio 2012. You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx)

It fully supports Windows Phone 8. Take a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/31/windows-phone-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012-update-2.aspx) guide on how to run tests from command-line.

If switching to the new framework is not an option, there is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970194/windows-phone-development-and-unit-testing/13035195#13035195) on SO regarding running `MSTest.exe` with Windows Phone 8. Look at point 4 - there describes how to copy right assemblies into project.

At the moment I don't have IDE to check your scenario with provided tools, but will provide update with test results as soon as possible.

Comment: It works ! Tests are now working flawlessly, at least for WP8. In case you get this error "Unit tests for Windows Store and Windows Phone apps cannot be run outside appcontainer. Create an app package and run tests in appcontainer m
ode." remember that VSTest requires you to run *.xap test file for WP8. Unfortunately I didn't manage to run the tests for WindowsStore application but I guess it requires a little bit more of configuration.